# pass onTap on parent component in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a re usable component in flutter:

re usable component:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ReusableCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const ReusableCard({required this.onTap});
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  @override
  State<ReusableCard> createState() => _ReusableCardState();
}

class _ReusableCardState extends State<ReusableCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
        elevation: 50,
        shadowColor: Colors.black,
        color: const Color.fromRGBO(185, 246, 202, 1),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: onTap, <<<---- my onTap function
          child: Row(children: const [
            Text("hello",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  color: Colors.black,
                )),
          ]),
        ));
  }
}
```

I am getting error at this onTap: `Undefined name 'onTap'. Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name`

I want to use my onTap function in my parent component:

```
body: const Center(
  child: ReusableCard(
    onTap: () {
      print("this is pressed")
    },
  ),
),
```

Here also I am getting error at onTap: `A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter of type 'void Function()' in a const constructor. Try using a subtype, or removing the keyword 'const'`

I am new to flutter and not able to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

While it is a `StatefulWidget` you need to use `widget.VariableName`

```dart
onTap: widget.onTap,
```